# Can a mysqldump be ported between windows and unix without impediments?

Tags: mysql

Can any anomalies occur when using a mysql dump created on a unix system on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever tool you're using to create the mysql dump will need to be careful with what it uses to end lines with. Windows uses \r\n to end all lines, while unix just uses \n. That's really the only thing you'll have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I develop on Windows machines and the production server is Unix (Apache on both), I've ported many MySQL databases to and from each without issue. So from my experience there shouldn't be any problems using a dump created on one on the other.